# How does this linear map transform a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I am new to this forum and I have a doubt with linear algebra, specifically linear maps and vectors. I have a linear map $R_\alpha =
    \begin{pmatrix}
    cos \alpha & - sin \alpha\\
    sin \alpha & cos \alpha\\
    \end{pmatrix}
$ and the question goes like, how does $R_\alpha$ transform a vector?

Can someone please help me? I am not sure if this sort of queston as been asked, I tried to google but I did not get any results regarding this problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So googling has replaced mathematical investigation? For a start, what does it do to the vector $\pmatrix{1\\0}$?

Comment: I think it returns $\begin{pmatrix}
    cos \alpha\\
    sin \alpha\\
    \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Now, can you describe this vector geometrically?

Comment: Is it rotation by $\alpha$ degrees?

Comment: OK, does that check with other vectors?

Comment: Yes, i feel like it does

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89200/discussion-between-vinay-bharadhwaj-and-lord-shark-the-unknown).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments above on the OP are good, but here's another perspective. How does $R_\alpha$ change the length of a vector? It is easy to verify that

$$R_\alpha^T R_\alpha=\begin{pmatrix}\cos^2 \alpha+\sin^2 \alpha & 0 \\ 0 & \cos^2 \alpha+\sin^2 \alpha \end{pmatrix}=I$$

So that for some vector $v$ we have $||R_\alpha v||^2=(R_\alpha v)^T (R_\alpha v)=v^T R_\alpha^T R_\alpha v=v^T I v=v^T v=||v||^2$. That is, $R_\alpha$ is an isometry (it can't change the length of vectors). So if $R_\alpha$ cannot change the length of a vector, it could only possibly rotate a vector. So what is this angle? We can compute the angle, $\theta$, between $R_\alpha v$ and $v$ by computing

$$\cos \theta=\frac{(R_\alpha v) \cdot v}{||R_\alpha v||\cdot||v||}.$$

I'll leave it to you to verify that this gives $\theta=\alpha$ (mod $\pi$ or whatever).